# Sending and receiving byte[] using socket

Tags: java

I have `Socket socket=new Socket(ipAddress, port);` in my code. I need to send `byte[]` and receive `byte[]` over that socket. How to do that, what wrappers to use (I always send `byte[]` and receive `byte[]`)?

Comment: Look at SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878867/how-to-send-an-array-of-bytes-over-a-tcp-connection-java-programming

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the tutorial on [Reading from and Writing to a Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html).

To write a byte array to a socket you would:

```
byte[] message = ...;
Socket socket=new Socket(ipAddress, port);
OutputStream socketOutputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
socketOutputStream.write(message);
```

Similarly, to read, you would use [`socket.getInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream%28%29).

Answer (score 4):

You don't need wrappers. Just call `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` on the socket object. The returned objects have `read(byte[])` and `write(byte[])` methods. Be careful to take the return value of `read(byte[])` into account (it returns the number of bytes *actually* read).

Answer (score 3):

On the server side, create a new [`ServerSocket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and call `accept()` on the socket object to accept incoming connections. (You may wish to handle the newly connected session in a new thread to avoid blocking the main thread.)

On the client side, create a new [`Socket`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#connect%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) and call `connect()` with the server's address and port to initiate the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
public static byte[] sendandrecive(byte[] message)
{
    byte[] real = null;

    try
    {
        Socket s=new Socket("192.9.200.4",2775);
        DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
        DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  

        dout.write(message, 0, message.length);
        dout.flush();  

        //dout.close();  

        byte[] data = new byte[1000];
        int count = dis.read(data);
        real =new byte[count+1];
        for(int i=1;i<=count;i++)
        real[i]=data[i];

        s.close();
        System.out.println("ok");

        }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return real;  
}
```

Comment: Hi, some explanations would significantly improve the quality of your answer