# Sending Bitmaps over Socket

Tags: android, sockets, bitmap

I'm sending `Bitmap` (decoded from files) over `Socket` and I'm worried that I wouldn't be able to `write()` all the `byte[]` with a single call.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
int cBytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
ByteBuffer cBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(cBytes);
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(cBuffer);
bitmap.recycle();
byte[] bitmapArray = cBuffer.array();
```

This is how I get my `byte[]`. So what's the way to send this array over `Socket`, should I divide this into chunks? like implementing a queue or something; or is there any class that could help me to do this sending?

Comment: I Googled and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878867/how-to-send-an-array-of-bytes-over-a-tcp-connection-java-programming

Sounds like you can do it using an OutputStream and an InputStream?

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually asking if this should be divided into chunks and queued, since a bitmap might have 12 million bytes (i.e. a 12 Megapixels image, I believe), and I don't think you can just `Socket#write(my12MillionBytesArray)`

Comment: The problem is not `Socket#write(my12MillionBytesArray)` ... the problem is : how to not crash the App with a `my12MillionBytesArray` in memory (even before trying to send those bytes over TCP)

Comment: If it is to send a file then do not use Bitmap and BitmapFactory. No need to load the whole file in memory either. Just open a FileInputStream for the file. Open a OutputStream on the socket.getOutputStream. Then make a loop where you read/write chunks of say 16385 bytes.

Comment: this is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, mind to write an answer with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

I using loopj's async http library, but here's how I'm doing it:

```
public void add_image_android(final Bitmap image) 
{ 
    final ByteArrayInputStream bs;
    final Bitmap targetBitmap;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, 
                                  image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 
                                  matrix, true);


    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    targetBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos); 
    byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
    bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmapdata);
    targetBitmap.recycle();

    String url = "http://www.somesite.com/api.php?callback=add_image";

    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("file", bs);
    params.put("is_android","Y");
    client.post(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response)
        {
            try 
            {
                bs.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ((ResponseListener)_mainContext).add_image_android_response(response.toString());
            return; 
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e) 
        {
            fireToast("api error:"+e);
            Log.d("api error:",e.toString());
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm using `Socket` not **HTTP** :(

Comment: Oh gotcha. I have no idea then :D Does your application require you to use sockets? Why not just use HTTP?

Comment: Requirements by my boss, I'd totally go for HTTP if it depended on me

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in a single write(). No chunking required. Your problem will be memory, not the write.